# How to subtract one Scala Spark DataFrame from another (Normalise to the mean)

Tags: scala, pandas, apache-spark

I have two Spark DataFrames:

df1 with 80 columns

```
CO01...CO80

+----+----+
|CO01|CO02|
+----+----+
|2.06|0.56|
|1.96|0.72|
|1.70|0.87|
|1.90|0.64|
+----+----+
```

and df2 with 80 columns

```
avg(CO01)...avg(CO80)
```

which is mean of each column

```
+------------------+------------------+
|         avg(CO01)|         avg(CO02)|
+------------------+------------------+
|2.6185106382978716|1.0080985915492937|
+------------------+------------------+
```

How can i subtract df2 from df1 for corresponding values?

I'm looking for solution that does not require to list all the columns.

P.S

In pandas it could be simply done by:

```
df2=df1-df1.mean()
```

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, for example:
|2.06-2.6185106382978716 |0.56-1.0080985915492937 |

Comment: and for the second row  |1.96-2.6185106382978716 |0.72-1.0080985915492937 | ?

Comment: Yes. For every row in corresponding column of df1 i want subtract row in  corresponding column of df2.

Comment: are the column names matching ? i.e. CO01 of df1 with avg(CO01) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
scala> val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
     | (2.06,0.56),
     | (1.96,0.72),
     | (1.70,0.87),
     | (1.90,0.64))).toDF("c1","c2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [c1: double, c2: double]

scala>

scala> def subMean(mean: Double) = udf[Double, Double]((value: Double) => value - mean)
subMean: (mean: Double)org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

scala>

scala> val result = df.columns.foldLeft(df)( (df, col) =>
     | { val avg = df.select(mean(col)).first().getAs[Double](0);
     | df.withColumn(col, subMean(avg)(df(col)))
     | })
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [c1: double, c2: double]

scala>

scala> result.show(10, false)
    +---------------------+---------------------+
|c1                   |c2                   |
+---------------------+---------------------+
|0.15500000000000025  |-0.13749999999999996 |
|0.05500000000000016  |0.022499999999999964 |
|-0.20499999999999985 |0.1725               |
|-0.004999999999999893|-0.057499999999999996|
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Hope, this helps!

Please note that, this will work for n number of columns as long as all columns in dataframe are of numeric type

Comment: np! If an answer has resolved your issue, kindly accept it - see What should I do when someone answers my question?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers